# Firebase databasereference initialization crashes app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-assistant

Firebase authentication works perfectly.

The project Structure is this where I added google service json file

[image: The project Structure is this where I added google service json file].

The app is connected with Firebase database

[image: Firebase database].

Whenever I just add `databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("message");` , The app crashes. I am not sure what I have done wrong. The crash report is

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method zzckb()Z in class Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp' appears in /data/app/com.example.kumarsaikat.firebaseone-hQwEzX_xqG5IhkEG8WahzQ==/base.apk)
>       at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Unknown Source:111)
>       at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Unknown Source:4)
>       at com.example.kumarsaikat.firebaseone.ProfileActivity.onCreate(ProfileActivity.java:38)
>       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7091)
>       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7082)
>       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1215)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2747)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2872)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1601)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6600)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:518)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:821)

Comment: Did you try to reinstall firebase dependency? it may refers to a problem with downloading it.

Comment: Here is a similar error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44447837/firebase-databasereference-gives-no-virtual-method-error

Comment: Show your database hierarchy

Comment: Please add your `build.gradle` file.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have figured it out by myself. What I noticed is that the same error can show for different configuration problems, as I have tested all throughout my day, which did not work for me. I am not saying they are wrong, I am saying my problem source was different.

Here what I found,
in the  **build.gradle(app)** in the dependencie

`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1 
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1''`

The versions were different for each of them. When  I made the same version for all of them and synced again, the project work. The last comment of [this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40106056/firebase-storage-crash-on-firebaseapp-initialization) helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the dependencies to the latest version available by just hovering your mouse on the following three and press(Alt+Shift+Enter) and Sync your Gradle.

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:?????

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:?????

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:?????

It worked for me :)